# AWS CloudFront with Regional Api Gateway and Custom Domain throwing 403s

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

I'm currently testing out how to setup CloudFront with Regional Api Gateway that includes a Custom Domain but have run into a bit of snag.

I would like to be able to use: https://mySuperDomain.com/rest/get_stuff

Setup:

**Api Gateway**

I have a *regional* Api Gateway that points to a Lambda function.

- The Gateway includes a Cognito Authorizer
- The Integration Request is a Lambda Proxy
- The base Resource is "/" with Methods: GET & OPTIONS
- The stage is "dev"
- Custom Domain name and ACM are set to "mySuperDomain.com"
- Configuration is also *Regional*

Directly calling the url works as expected: https://XXXXXXXX.execute-api.REGION.amazonaws.com/dev

**Route53**

- *A* record is an *alias* that points to the CloudFront Distribution
- Base domain also contains NS, SOA, and MX

**CloudFront**

Origins:

- Alternate Domain Names: www.mySuperDomain.com & mySuperDomain.com
- Origin and Domain Path: XXXXXXXX.execute-api.REGION.amazonaws.com/dev
- HTTPS only

Behaviors:

- /rest/*
- Origin group is set to the Origin
- HTTPS only

This is where things get confusing.
When including no headers, I get a "Missing Authentication Token" error. This signals to me that I'm hitting the correct endpoint but the Authentication Token is not making it through CloudFront.
However, when I whitelist what I describe as the kitchen sink: "Authorization, Host, Origin, Referer, Accept-Datetime", I get 403 Forbidden when calling: https://mySuperDomain.com/rest/get_stuff.

What am I missing in order to access the specified custom domain URL? Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: You do know that setting Origin Path to `/dev` and requesting `/rest/foo` from CloudFront forwards a request to the origin with the path set to `/dev/rest/foo` not `/dev/foo`... right?

Comment: What would be a potential solution then? Would I then change the Api Gateway stage to "rest" followed by {proxy+} in order to match?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.  Was this the root of the problem?

Comment: I added a stage titled "rest" with {proxy+}. I tried having the Origin Domain Name and Path be empty or include "/rest" with no luck. Still returning 403s.

Comment: Origin Domain Name can't be empty, but Origin Path should be.  Also you need to remove `Host` from header whitelisting if it's still there.

Comment: Brilliant! I removed all headers from the behavior except Authorization and that did it. Thanks for the assistance and patience. If posted below I would love to give it the right answer check.